# Should trivial default constructor respect default member initializer here?

Tags: c++, c++14, atomic, default-constructor, member-initialization

Consider the code:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

struct stru {
  int a{};
  int b{};
};

int main() {
  std::atomic<stru> as;
  auto s = as.load();
  std::cout << s.a << ' ' << s.b << std::endl;
}
```

Note that although `stru` has default member initializer, it still qualifies as an aggregate type since C++14. `std::atomic` has a trivial default constructor. According to the standard, should the members of `as` be initialized to zero? clang 6.0.0 doesn't do this (see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qHGGR66seZOkmH7c)), while gcc 7.2.0 seems so (see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nlKKeEWJyy50Yzn4)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, I think both compilers are right, in that your program exhibits undefined behavior. To quote n4140 (C++14), [[atomics.types.operations.req]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/atomics.types.operations.req), emphasis mine:

> In the following operation definitions:
>
> - an A refers to one of the atomic types.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> A::A() noexcept = default;
> ```
>
> *Effects*: leaves the atomic object in an **uninitialized** state. [ Note: These semantics ensure compatibility with C.  — end note ]

`as` is uninitialized before the load. So the usual spiel about undefined behavior must follow.

Comment: But one can do value/zero-initialization with `std::atomic<stru> as{}` and guarantee the members are zero, right?

Comment: @Lingxi - No. That consructor is defined as defaulted, with the specified  effect of not doing initialization. Value initializing it is gonna call the same c'tor.

Comment: But it's said on [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) that *if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor*. So zero-initialization applies here, making constructors irrelevant. No?

Comment: @Lingxi - It would, if the standard did not explicitly demand otherwise, which it does.

Comment: @Lingxi - Recall that the standard library types are not always subject to the same constraints as user defined types. For example, you can't create a non-empty `std::initializer_list`, except a non-empty one is created for you every time you use list initialization and so forth.

Comment: I think the standard text you quoted only says about the trivial default constructor, but nothing about value-initialization.

Comment: @Lingxi - I'm afraid that's wishful thinking on your part. The standard text is clear, from the POV of the abstract machine, this is an uninitialized object.

Comment: I cannot get it still. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49400942/1348273).

Answer (score 0):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic) the `std::atomic::atomic()` constructor doesn't initialize the obj:

> ```
> atomic() noexcept = default;
> ```
>
> 1) The default constructor is trivial: no initialization takes place
>   other than zero initialization of static and thread-local objects.
>   std::atomic_init may be used to complete initialization.