# Does value initialization work for atomic objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, atomic, value-initialization

By *work* here, I take to mean that `std::atomic<T> a{}` effectively zero initializes `a`. I have always been thinking so and have been practically using it until [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387069/should-trivial-default-constructor-respect-default-member-initializer-here#comment85776557_49387259). Before explaining my understanding of this, I want to show that, at the very least, gcc and clang are doing it in practice.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  using atomic = std::atomic<int>;  
  auto p = (atomic*)operator new(sizeof(atomic));
  std::memset(p, -1, sizeof(atomic));
  new(p) atomic{};
  std::cout << p->load() << std::endl;
}
```

The output is `0` on both [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2yHHirzWItwrHKZO) and [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fS05EI6wdc1T8SSR).

Following is my explanation of why this should work (you may think otherwise, of course). The standard says that

> In the following operation definitions:
>
> - an A refers to one of the atomic types.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> A::A() noexcept = default;
> ```
>
> *Effects*: leaves the atomic object in an uninitialized state. [ Note: These semantics ensure compatibility with C.  — end note ]

It basically says that the default constructor is trivial and does nothing. I'm OK with this, but I don't see how this makes value initialization non-applicable. According to [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), the effects of value initialization include (emphasis mine):

> if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither
>   user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an
>   implicitly-defined or **defaulted default constructor**), the object is
>   zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a
>   non-trivial default constructor;

`std::atomic` has a defaulted default constructor, so the object is

1. zero-initialized and then
2. it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor.

Point 2 doesn't apply here since the defaulted default constructor is trivial, but I don't see any statement that renders point 1 in-effective. Is my understanding correct or am I missing something?

Comment: In the question you link to, the atomic variable is not explicitly initialized, so the default constructor is used. And it does nothing. But you explicitly initialize your variable, invoking the value initialization machinery that you describe, so you're good.

Comment: All that stuff with placement new etc. is just distraction.

Comment: Alright, you made me go verify the assumptions I made in the comments to the other post. So I apologize for that. You are correct.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The placement new is needed to show that the zero is indeed a result of value initialization, not some junk value happen to be there.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks for the confirmation. I'm finally confident now :)

Comment: The issue is that `std::atomic<T>` under the present wording is not required to contain a `T`. You can zero the bytes in the `atomic` but that's not enough to reason about the `T` value it refers to. This is obviously a suboptimal state of affairs; there's a paper in flight to change this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately the crux of the matter for the value initialization case is in [[dcl.init]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#7), bullets 1 and 2:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause [class]) with a user-provided constructor ([class.ctor]), then the default constructor
>     for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no
>     accessible default constructor);
> - T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if
>     T's implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that
>     constructor is called.
> - ...

Which of the two bullets above is applied depends on the c'tor being user-provided. What I didn't remember in the comments to the other answer, is the intricacies of `= default;` when applied to that. If we look at the definition given at [[dcl.fct.def.default]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.fct.def.default#4) (emphasis mine):

> Explicitly-defaulted functions and implicitly-declared functions are
>   collectively called defaulted functions, and the implementation shall
>   provide implicit definitions for them ([class.ctor] [class.dtor],
>   [class.copy]), which might mean defining them as deleted. **A special
>   member function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not
>   explicitly defaulted** or deleted on its first declaration. **A
>   user-provided explicitly-defaulted function (i.e., explicitly
>   defaulted after its first declaration)** is defined at the point where
>   it is explicitly defaulted; if such a function is implicitly defined
>   as deleted, the program is ill-formed. [ Note: Declaring a function as
>   defaulted after its first declaration can provide efficient execution
>   and concise definition while enabling a stable binary interface to an
>   evolving code base. — end note ]

We see that the default c'tor of `atomic` **is not user provided**, because it is declared as defaulted, as opposed to being declared and then defined as defaulted. So the second bullet of [dcl.init]/7 is applicable, the object is zero-initialized, followed by the (non-)invocation of the (trivial default) constructor which does nothing.

Comment: Your answer was a reasonable interpretation of the specs (since C++20). However, [P0883](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0883r2.pdf) explicitly stated that for `atomic`, an empty braced-init-list didn't work (, and default initialization didn't do anything, unexpectedly). Thus, your [initial comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387069/should-trivial-default-constructor-respect-default-member-initializer-here#comment85776557_49387259) that the question linked to was correct (until C++20). What do you think? How do you reconcile these differences?

Comment: See also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099401/why-does-default-constructor-of-stdatomic-not-default-initialize-the-underlyin) and [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62184221/initialization-of-stdatomic-before-and-after-c20) that discussed the same issue.

Comment: @Daniel - I don't need to reconcile any differences. The object being zero initialized never meant it was initialized with a usable atomic value (unless the implementation was written in such a way). C++20 changed it on two fronts. For one, IIRC a user-declared c'tor (instead of user-provided) will no longer do zero-initialization. And then there's the atomic papers themselves.

Comment: Sure, but P0883 explicitly said `std::atomic<int> x{};      // does NOT zero initialize`. It didn't say `// does zero initialize but the atomic might not be usable`. Anyway, thanks for replying.

Comment: @Daniel - It does zero initialize... just not necessarily what one would expect to be zero initialized. `std::atomic` could very well be hiding a platform specific API the returns a handle to an atomic object. Now, you'd get a zero handle, but not a zero atomic object.