# Initialisation of vector of atomics

Tags: c++, vector, atomic

Consider:

```
void foo() {
  std::vector<std::atomic<int>> foo(10);
  ...
}
```

Are the contents of foo now valid? Or do I need to explicitly loop through and initialise them? I have checked on Godbolt and it seems fine, however the standard seems to be very confused on this point.

The [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) constructor says it inserts [default-inserted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable) instances of `std::atomic<int>`, which are [value initialised](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) via placement `new`.

I think this effect of value initialisation applies:

> 2) if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor;

So it seems to me that the atomics are zero-initialised. So the question is, does zero-initialisation of a `std::atomic<int>` result in a valid object?

I'm going to guess that the answer is "yes in practice but it's not really defined"?

Note: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49401193/265521) agrees that it is zero-initialised, but doesn't really say if that means that the object is valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct to be worried. According to standard the atomics has the default constructor called, however they have *not* been initialized as such. This is because the default constructor doesn't initialize the atomic:

> The default-initialized `std::atomic<T>` does not contain a `T` object,
>   and its only valid uses are destruction and initialization by
>   [std::atomic_init](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_init)

This is somewhat in violation of the normal language rules, and some implementations initialize anyway (as you have noted).

That being said, I would recommend taking the extra step to make 100% sure they are initialized correctly according to standard - after all you are dealing with concurrency where bugs can be extremely hard to track down.

There are many ways to dodge the issue, including using wrapper:

```
struct int_atomic {
   std::atomic<int> atomic_{0};//use 'initializing' constructor
};
```

Comment: Or actually use `atomic_init`. You already have to synchronise around the code in the question anyway

Comment: The default constructor is trivial so it _isn't_ called anyway (per the quote in the question)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica that is also a possible, I just want'ed to highlight the wrapper

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica this is an exception to the normal language rules - even though some compilers don't implement this exception. Im not sure the StoreTeller answer is 100% accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the default constructor were called (it isn't, because it's trivial) [it doesn't really do anything](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic).

Zero-initialisation obviously cannot be guaranteed to produce a valid atomic; this'll only work if *by chance* a valid atomic is created by zero-initialising all its members.

And, since atomics aren't copyable, you can't provide a initialisation value in the vector constructor.

You should now loop over the container and [`std::atomic_init`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_init) each element. If you need to lock around this, that's fine because you're already synchronising the vector's creation for the same reason.

Comment: @darune I consider that a kind of synchronisation ;)