# Initialization of std::atomic before and after C++20

Tags: c++, c++17, atomic, c++20

Consider the following two lines of code:

```
std::atomic_flag a { };                // Since C++20
std::atomic_flag a = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT; // Until C++20
```

In C++20, the first line initializes `a` to the clear state, but if I use that in C++17, `a` will be initialized to an unspecified state. The second line is deprecated in C++20, but in C++ 17, it initializes `a` to the clear state. How can I have them both in a code? I guess I should use a macro, but what is that macro exactly? And does it work for the initialization of all the other `std::atomic<T>` types?

Comment: I'd recommend starting with a list of [feature test macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test).

Comment: @chris Wouldn't that require c++20 already?

Comment: @cigien, I haven't checked, but I wouldn't be surprised if implementations offer them in non-C++20 modes. There was definitely a followed-in-practice recommendation for feature testing before C++20 as well.

Comment: The second form is still valid. “Deprecated” means that it **might** be removed in the future.

Comment: I got sidetracked seeing `__cplusplus` mentioned. I double checked and my suspicion was correct in MSVC/GCC/Clang, but I concur, worry about deprecated things when they're removed. _That's_ the point where you need to have different code or forego C++17 support. It might not be as pretty as starting fresh from C++20, but it gets the job done just as well in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @chris comment, I think the following code will do the job:

```
#if __has_cpp_attribute(__cpp_lib_atomic_value_initialization)
std::atomic_flag a { };
#else
std::atomic_flag a = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
#endif
```

The required macros are defined in either one of `<memory>`, `<atomic>`, and `<version>` header files. I certainly don't want to write something that is already deprecated (ie, the use is allowed, but discouraged for some reason).

Comment: `__has_cpp_attribute` is for checking C++ attributes (`nodiscard`, `deprecated`, etc.). To test for a language or library feature macro use plain `#if ...` (`#if __cpp_lib_atomic_value_initialization` or `#if __cpp_lib_atomic_value_initialization >= 201911L` in this case). `#if __has_cpp_attribute(...)` might have work by accident, because that's a C++20 feature as well.

Answer (score 5):

`atomic_flag` is special. It is logically equivalent to an `atomic<bool>`, but the committee learned their lesson about having unique specializations with different behavior, so they made a completely separate type rather than a specialization of `atomic` for `bool`s.

All `atomic<T>`s can be initialized by giving it a value of type `T` (so that's how you can get around the pre-C++20 value initialization nonsense). `atomic_flag` cannot be given a `bool`, since it doesn't store a `bool`. This is why it has that special `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` macro.

`ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` may be deprecated, but it's not gone in C++20, so you are free to use it. In the [relatively unlikely event](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2139r0.html#3.24) that it gets removed for C++23, by then you should hopefully no longer have to support C++17.

Answer (score 3):

If you need your code to work with both pre C++20 and C++20 then use `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT`. It's deprecated in C++20 because it is no longer needed, but it is still supported so it will work in C++20 as it worked before.